# Expo firebase auth currentUser undefined on android only

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I used google SignIn button in my Expo app like this:

```
const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
 androidClientId: ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
 iosClientId: IOS_CLIENT_ID,
});
...
useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === "success") {
      handleUserLogin(response.authentication);
    }
}, [response]);
```

everything is fine until this part in handleUserLogin

```
const handleUserLogin = async (
    authentication: AuthenticationType["body"]
  ) => {
    try {
      const idToken = await _auth
        .app()
        .currentUser?.getIdToken(true)
...
```

the problem is this currentUser is always undefined on Android, but on iOS everything works and i can getIdToken from currentUser

_auth is my helper function for firebase auth:

```
import {
  initializeAuth,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithCredential,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  getAuth,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from "firebase/auth";

// initialize firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// initialize auth
const authApp = initializeAuth(firebaseApp, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
});

const _auth = {
  app: () => authApp,
  getAuth: getAuth,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword: signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithCredential: signInWithCredential,
  GoogleAuthProvider: GoogleAuthProvider,
  onAuthStateChanged: onAuthStateChanged,
};
```

i also tried

```
  useEffect(() => {
    _auth.onAuthStateChanged(_auth.app(), (user: any) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log("onAuthStateChanged", user);
      } else {
        console.log("onAuthStateChanged", "NO USER");
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

but even this works fine in iOS but not on Android!